# Explicit instantiation of template when passing argument by reference

Tags: c++, templates, clang, c++14, pass-by-reference

**How can I explicitly instantiate a template function with an argument passed by reference?**

I have a simple templated function which takes any type and turns it into a string:

```
template <typename T>
string to_string (const T &e) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    string str;
    ss << e;
    ss >> str;
    return str;
}
```

Notice the argument parameter `e` is passed by reference.

I now want to explicitly instantiate the function for different datatypes, for example:

```
template string to_string<string> (string);
template string to_string<double> (double);
```

However, the compiler complains (due to the explicit instantiation):

> error: explicit instantiation of 'to_string' does not refer to a function template, variable template, member function, member class, or static data member
>
> **template string to_string (string);**

If I change the argument of the templated function from `const T &e` to `const T e` - i.e. removing the reference - it compiles and works fine.

**How can I explicitly instantiate a template function with an argument passed by reference?**

Toolchain:

- C++14
- clang version 11.0.0 (MacOS)

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std;` since there is a `std::to_string` function

Comment: `T` and `const T` are equivalent parameter types. `T` and `const T&` are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify the paramters as reference in the explicit instantiation too. Otherwise they won't match the function template's signature. E.g. if `T` is `double`, then the parameter type `const T&` should be `const double&`.

```
template string to_string<string> (const string&);
template string to_string<double> (const double&);
```